How to open a directory from current location using lf and other terminal hygene
I like using the command line but I find myself falling back on the GUI and mouse.
Is there a way to open a bash terminal in the current location you're navigated to in lf? Navigating to a directory using cd is such a pain.
Is there a way to copy to clipboard text in the terminal?
Highlighting and right-clicking to copy is ridiculous, I must be doing things like a simpleton.

You can use the default binding w to open a shell in the currently selected directory. It uses the directory listed in the first (left-hand) column as its target, so you might have to → into empty first.
Read man lf to find out about this (search for shell, as an example).
The examples there show how w is bound, and it wouldn't be at all difficult to create a mapping that opened your preferred terminal application in the current directory. Something like this perhaps to define S:
map S &x-terminal-emulator

For copy and paste, I find single/double/triple clicking perfectly effective, and then using middle click to paste.

Nice! I also found https://github.com/gokcehan/lf/issues/631;  you can also press $ in lf and then run your terminal (e.g. terminator) and it will open at that directory. Your w is clearly easier though.

w is bound to $ and $SHELL, so quite similar

Chris, clicking is ridiculous, but because your first answer about 'w' in lf was so fantastic I'll forgive you. (ha ha) Surely there's some equivalent to Ctrl + Shift + c in lf to copy the the name of the highlighted file.....Anyway, Thanks very much for the great answer!

@1toneboy there isn't a clipboard except under the GUI. You could probably map another key in lf to send the currently selected file name to xclip, but I haven't looked. And you'd still need to click-to-paste
